# problems using WinINet in MFC

Tags: c++, url, mfc, wininet

I'm using WinINet class in MFC to upload files to webserver.
When I run this program, httpSendRequestEx returns 12005 error which is invalid url.
If I put http:// in front of the url, httpSendRequestEx returns 12007 error which is "The server name could not be resolved".
I spent whole day to fix this problem, but I have no idea how to fix it.
Please help me

Here is my code.

```
CString m_strBoundary = ("abcdefg");
LPCTSTR lpszFilePath = "C:\\MFCprj\\WinINet_Example2\\WinINet_Example2\\Full.jpg";
LPCTSTR lpszFileName = "Full.jpg";;
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile("C:\\MFCprj\\WinINet_Example2\\WinINet_Example2\\Full.jpg", GENERIC_READ, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

HINTERNET hInternet = ::InternetOpen("WININETEXAMPLE", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
if(!hInternet)
{
    AfxMessageBox("InternetOpen has an error");
}

HINTERNET hConnection = ::InternetConnect(hInternet, "192.168.88.4:8090/mrbs/controller?do=XML_MULTIPART_TEST_ACTION", INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, NULL); 
if(!hConnection)                                      
{
    AfxMessageBox("InternetConnect has an error");
}

HINTERNET hRequest = ::HttpOpenRequest(hConnection, "POST", "/jsp/inc/head.jsp", NULL, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE, 0);
if(!hRequest)
{
    AfxMessageBox("HttpOpenRequest has an error");
}

//HTTP header
_bstr_t strHeader;
strHeader = "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=";
strHeader = strHeader + m_strBoundary;
::HttpAddRequestHeaders(hRequest, (LPCTSTR)strHeader, -1, 0);

//Body header
_bstr_t strFilePartHead("--");
strFilePartHead = strFilePartHead + m_strBoundary;
strFilePartHead = strFilePartHead + "\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"Full.jpg\"";
strFilePartHead = strFilePartHead + "\"\r\nContent-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel\r\n\r\n";

_bstr_t strFilePartTail("\r\n");
strFilePartTail = strFilePartTail + "--";
strFilePartTail = strFilePartTail + m_strBoundary;
strFilePartTail = strFilePartTail + "--\r\n";

INTERNET_BUFFERS BufferIn;
BufferIn.dwStructSize = sizeof(INTERNET_BUFFERS);
BufferIn.Next = NULL;
BufferIn.lpcszHeader = (LPCTSTR)strHeader;
BufferIn.dwBufferLength = 0;
BufferIn.dwBufferTotal = GetFileSize(lpszFilePath) + strlen( (LPCSTR)strFilePartHead ) + strlen( (LPCSTR)strFilePartTail );
BufferIn.dwHeadersLength = lstrlen( (LPCTSTR)strHeader );
BufferIn.dwHeadersTotal = lstrlen( (LPCTSTR)strHeader );
BufferIn.lpvBuffer = NULL;
BufferIn.dwOffsetHigh = 0;
BufferIn.dwOffsetLow = 0;

if(!::HttpSendRequestEx(hRequest, &BufferIn, NULL, 0, NULL))
{
    DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
    ::InternetCloseHandle(hRequest);
    ::InternetCloseHandle(hConnection);
    ::InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);
}
```

Comment: This isn't MFC, you could use `WinAPI` tag instead of `MFC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InternetConnect` accepts only the server name/address, and the port.

```
hConnection = ::InternetConnect(hInternet, "192.168.88.4", 8090, ...);
```

That's because `InternetConnect` only makes a connection to a server (a port on a machine somewhere). The URL forms part of the request to the server, so the additional string (*"/mrbs/controller?do=XML_MULTIPART_TEST_ACTION"*) you were passing to `InternetConnect` actually needs to be given to `HttpOpenRequest`.

```
hRequest = ::HttpOpenRequest(hConnection, "POST", "/mrbs/controller?do=XML_MULTIPART_TEST_ACTION", ...);
```

I'm not sure where the *"/jsp/inc/head.jsp"* that you were originally passing to `HttpOpenRequest` fits in, but if that really is part of the URL too then you would do this:

```
hRequest = ::HttpOpenRequest(hConnection, "POST", "/mrbs/controller?do=XML_MULTIPART_TEST_ACTION/jsp/inc/head.jsp", ...);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. hRequest = ::HttpOpenRequest(hConnection, "POST", "/mrbs/controller?do=XML_MULTIPART_TEST_ACTION", ...); It works for me now.

Comment: Can I ask one more question? I try to upload a image file to the server, but only 4kb is uploaded. What should I modify to get enough buffer??

Comment: @JunHyunPark I don't know that sorry, you're probably better off posting that as a new question.